# Angular Prerender Throws ENAMETOOLONG error for file paths under 260 characters

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, prerender

I am attempting to prerender a large amount of content.   However, Angular Prender will throw an error on paths over ~25 characters.

The Error is `An unhandled exception occurred: spawn ENAMETOOLONG`

I know the gist of the error is paths cannot exceed a certain length. On Windows, it's 260 characters.  However, if I measure the lengths of all the paths by adding up the output directory and the route path, no route exceeds 186 characters, which is well under the 260 character limit.

I attempted to fix it by modifying the registry to use long file paths and restarted my computer, but I still got the same error.    I believe it's because the Angular Prerender process uses the 32bit windows cmd line.  I looked underneath the hood in the `@nguniversal\builders\src\prerender` and noticed it uses the `fork` method instead of `spawn` or exec, meaning it won't take the shell argument.

I have also tried running it in Powershell, which I think is 64bit, but no luck.

Route file sample:

```
/en-us/
/en-us/about
/en-us/register
/en-us/login
/en-us/explore
/en-us/help/support
/en-us/forgot
/en-us/contentcategory/url
```

Environment

```
Windows 10 64bit
Node 14.15 (64bit)
Angular 10.2.4
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1001.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1002.3
@angular-devkit/core            10.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      10.2.3
@angular/cli                    10.2.3
@nguniversal/builders           10.1.0
@nguniversal/express-engine     10.1.0
@schematics/angular             10.2.3
@schematics/update              0.1002.3
rxjs                            6.5.5
typescript                      4.0.7
```

Comment: And you are not using a mapped network drive? (i.e. `D:` pointing to `\\server.xx.yy\folder`)

Comment: No the path is akin to `c:\repos\<projects>\dist\project\browser`